# LaTeX plugin for editing in nvim

Tags: neovim, filetype-tex

I have moved from Emacs to Neovim and are trying to make my life easier while editing LaTeX documents.

One of the things I liked above Emacs's LaTeX plugin was the ability to white `"word"` and then the plugin would automatically convert it to the way of writing quotes that would be ``` ``word'' ```.

There were other ways the plugin worked, such as syntax highlighting, as well as highlighting color parenthesis and completions.

I have looked all around Vim/Neovim and it is easy to get confused with so much stuff on git, much of what I do not completely understand and is likely irrelevant to my needs.

One of the things I liked about Emacs was that the file extension automagically went into LaTeX/BibTex or HTML or C/C++ or Fortran or python or other modes. I am sure that all this is possible, but I am unclear as to what makes this do reliably.

Comment: Plugin requests are off-topic, and this may be too broad anyway (you need to clarify exactly what task you want to accomplish).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A popular choice to edit LaTeX is the [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plugin.

The [vim-latex](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) plugin is another choice that seems to offer the 'Smart Quote' functionality you mention.

For the feature you mention you can implement it using the following command:

```
:inoremap <expr> " getline('.')[col('.')-2] != ' ' ? "''" : "``"
```

If you prefer the feature to be active only for the TeX/LaTeX file you could add the following lines in your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file

```
augroup latexquote
  autocmd FileType tex,plaintex inoremap <buffer><expr> " (col('.') < 2 \|\| getline('.')[col('.')-2] == ' ') ? "``" : "''"
augroup END
```

Neovim will detect the `filetype` based on the file extension and the content of the file (`.tex` or `.latex`)

To install the plugin you can clone the repository into:

- `~/.config/nvim/pack/dist/start` (if you run Linux or MacOS)
- `~\AppData\Local\nvim\pack\dist\start` (if your run Windows)

You can also install a plugin manager. There are a number of popular choices:

- [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)
- [lazy.nvim](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim)

To answer the part of your question about LaTeX vs. Html vs. Python I can confirm that Vim/Neovim support that in the following way:

- Vim associate to every buffer a `filetype` (e.g. `tex`, `html`, `python`, ...)
- Vim associate to every file type a number of customizations

  - Syntax highlighting
  - Dedicated keyboard mappings (like the one I propose you for smart quotation)
  - Customization of the `make` command (e.g. to compile LaTeX file for `tex` file and C++ programs for `cpp` file)
  - LSP integration
  - And many more..

A number of these `filetype` customization come with the bare Vim/Neovim configuration but can be extended by customization or plugins.

Comment: Thank you, sorry, I neglected to mention in my post that I only use linux, have done so for the past twenty seven years. Before that, I used unix. Thank you for the references. I will try vimtex and also wait to see if other suggestions come in. Does the vimtex plugin also work on BibTeX/BibLaTeX extensions?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: I did install vimtex and also your suggested snippet for the smartquote functionality, but it does not seem to do anything. I placed the chunk of text in my `$HOME/.config/nvim/init.vim` at the very end.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I'll have a second look :-/

Comment: The mapping makes that when you type `"`  in a `tex` buffer Vim insert instead ` `` ` if you are at the start of a word (there is a preceding space) or `''` if you are at the end of the word. To verify that the buffer is a `tex` buffer type the following command `:set ft?`. If you open a file with the `.tex` or `.latex` extension it should be of type `.tex`

Comment: I have improved the mapping such that. It works also for `plaintex`, It works for the start of the line.

Comment: Thank you for this, it works! I will get back to you in case i have more questions/concerns.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Your questions are Welcome :-)